# detect significant changes in a data list

Tags: python, statistics, data-analysis

I have a list of data in python that represents number of jobs in time. I want to detect significant changes in this dataset. What I mean is that I wanna detect every time data value increases or decreases by more than a particular percentage from the last checkpoint.

For example, if I have data like `[10,..,10,100,..,100,200,200,...,100,10]`. There are 4 significant changes.

What will be the ideal method/algorithm to detect this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the absolute difference between the current and next list elements and report its index if the difference exceeds certain threshold, e.g.:

```
THR = 50
data = [10,10,100,100,200,200,100,10]
[(i,abs(x-y)>THR) for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(data,data[1:])) if abs(x-y)>THR]
#[1, 3, 5, 6] - gap after items 1 (10->100), 3 (100->200), etc.
```

Comment: How can I handle it for scenarios where the change is more gradual like the example given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43722597/detect-significant-changes-in-a-data-set-that-gradually-changes  ?

Comment: Well, change the THR?

Answer (score 1):

If the variance of the data is constant, you can use standard deviation. If the data already exists (not listening live), you can use pandas:

```
p=10 #instead of measuring difference from previous 1, can measure longer-distance differences (though this may not be exactly what you're asking)
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(data)
diffs = s.diff(periods=p)
std = diffs.std()
significant_changes = diffs.loc[diffs > std]
```